# java.lang.IllegalAccessException when trying to generate JWT when calling .compact() in jjwt

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, jjwt, illegalaccessexception

As the title says, I'm trying to generate a JWT using jjwt in my spring boot starter web app and I hit this exception when I call compact() on the builder to actually return the JWT. More specifically:

`class io.jsonwebtoken.impl.lang.OptionalMethodInvoker cannot access class sun.security.util.KeyUtil (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.security.util to unnamed module`

I've just been following the guide on the jjwt GitHub page: https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt

(Not sure if this is too relevant) but I'm using JDK corretto-20 with gradle 8.3 on Intellij IDEA. My jjwt dependencies in my build.gradle.kts:

```
implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.12.0")
runtimeOnly("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.12.0")
runtimeOnly("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.12.0")
```

and the basic authenticator I've made so far which tries to generate the JWT:

```
package myproject.utility;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import myproject.model.User;

import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

public class Authenticator {
  private final static SecretKey secretKey = Jwts.SIG.HS256.key().build();

  public static String generateJwt(User user) {
    return Jwts.builder().claim("username", user.getUsername()).signWith(Authenticator.secretKey).compact();
  }
}
```

To pinpoint which bit was throwing the error I added each part of the JWT build process one at a time and it fails after calling compact() at the final step

The error feels pretty self-explanatory but I have no idea how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: [This appears to be a problem in the 0.12.0 release yesterday](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/issues/849) that was [fixed by 0.12.1 a few minutes ago](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/releases/tag/0.12.1) (life on the bleeding edge can be dangerous)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Ah yeah I started using jjwt just when 0.12.0 was released. Couldn't have been better timed to run into that problem XD cheers!